# iOS: How to pass index of row which is in section

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a tableview structure like this,

> Section 1
>
> ----> Row 1
>
> ----> Row 2
>
> ----> Row 3
>
> Section 2
>
> ----> Row 1
>
> ----> Row 2
>
> Section 3
>
> ----> Row 1
>
> ----> Row 2
>
> ----> Row 3
>
> ----> Row 4

How to get index of particular row that I have to pass, like i have to get index of 2nd row from 3rd section ? Consider I have to pass exact address/index/location of 2nd row from 3rd section.

Comment: at which point do you want to get it??

Comment: what exactly do you mean with `get index of particular row`? do you want to create the `NSIndexPath` for that instance?

Comment: Making more simple if I have to pass index of row to mutable array like this, [courseIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; where courseIds is my mutable array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a subclass of UITableViewCell, and add two properties to it

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger row;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger section;
```

then in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you can set these values according to the index path.

and once you want to pass the row&section info just use delegation or KVO

Answer (score 0):

- indexPathForRow:inSection:
  Returns an index-path object initialized with the indexes of a specific row and section in a table view.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSIndexPath/indexPathForRow:inSection: